password authentication failure while connecting to Neon postgres db
I am working on a Nodejs/Express application, and I am trying to connect to a newly created Neon postgres database with knex ORM. My knexfile.js file is below. I have taken the values of all the env variables (PGHOST, PGDATABASE, PGUSER, PGPASSWORD) from the Neon database credentials. However, while running the migration command npx knex migrate:latest --knexfile db/knexfile, I am getting the error error: password authentication failed for user "darkk"
Here, darkk is my Windows laptop username through which I login to my laptop. I don't know why this username is being used to log into the Neon database, when I have already provided the correct credentials to connect to the Neon db. Also, I am able to successfully connect to the Neon db using my locally installed pgAdmin 4 application, so I am clueless as to why through my Nodejs application I am unable to connect.
Can anyone please help me get rid of this error?
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
dotenv.config();

const knexConfig = {
  development: {
    client: 'pg',
    connection: {
      host: process.env.PGHOST,
      port: process.env.PGPORT || 5432,
      database: process.env.PGDATABASE,
      user: process.env.PGUSER,
      password: String(process.env.PGPASSWORD),
    },
    pool: {
      min: 2,
      max: 10,
    },
    migrations: {
      tableName: 'knex_migrations',
    },
  },
};

export default knexConfig;


Because by default the user name for a connection when one is not provided is the OS user name that the connection code is running as. This is the case for libpq based clients, which I assume is what is being used here. That would indicate that this process.env.PGUSER is not actually fetching anything or it being set to darkk .  Hard code a user name and password that you know works into knexfile.js and see if that works.

I noticed a strange thing. When I log the env variables before the knexConfig object setup, the correct values are logged. However, when I am trying to use these env variables like process.env.PGUSER, process.env.PGPASSWORD, etc. then I am getting this password authentication failed error. However, if I replace them with the hardcoded value for the connection string connection: postgresql://[username]:[password]@[hostname]/[dbname]?sslmode=require, then suddenly the migration becomes successful. Why is this happening?

To me that indicates that you are working in a different environment when you try to connect. What do process.env.PGUSER and process.env.PGPASSWORD return in the script? Add this information and that in your previous post as text update to question text.
